# how to pass, from a class to another, the name of a variable (NOT the value)

Tags: android

I need to pass name of a variable created in `Class A` to the `Class B`, so I can put a value in that variable (in `Class B`).
But, in Class B I do not know the name of that variable.
The code is something like this:

Class A

```
public class A {
      int valore; // this is the variable, in Class b, I don't know this name!
      public  void callClassB(){
            ClassB.Method(what shoudld i put here?)
      }
}
```

This is the Class B

```
public class B {              
       public void Method(the_Name_Of_TheVariable_I_get){
             the_Name_Of_TheVariable_I_get = 5; // i need to do this
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use reflection for this.

Here is a tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

You cant get the name of variable at runtime though. But assuming you have the name of the field the code would look something like this:

```
this.getClass().getDeclaredField(the_Name_Of_TheVariable_I_get).set(this, 5);
```

Comment: no, a this.getClass() is the B class, which doesn't have the field

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the variable name? Simply pass the variable itself. In class B create a method

```
public int getValore(){
         return valore;
}
```

Then in Class A use modify the code as

```
public  void callClassB(){
            ClassB.Method(getValore())
       }
```

I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: In class B i have to modify the value of a variable created in class A. But, in class B i don't know the name of the variable. So i need to pass the variable itself to the class B. It must be something dynamic. In class A i could have 100 variables, and in Class B, i don't know their name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following appraoch:

```
interface ValueSetter {
      void setValue(int value);
}
```

Class A

```
public class A implements ValueSetter{
int valore;

      public  void callClassB(){
            ClassB.Method(this)
       }

         void setValue(int value){
            valore = value;
         }
}
```

This is the class B

```
public class B{      

          public  void Method(ValueSetter valueSetter){
               ValueSetter.setValue(5); 
           }
    }
```

This is more inline with OOPS..

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the name of the variable `"valore"`, then you need reflection to assign it in your method :

```
a = new A();
Field f = a.getClass().getDeclaredField(varName);
f.set(a, 5);
```

a can be a parameter too. (it is necessary to give the instance that possesses the member).

However, this is not a recommended way of treating your issue, as it is unreliable in the sense that the compiler will not be able to check you are accessing items that actually exist.

It would be better to use an interface, for instance :

```
public interface Settable {
    public void set(int value);
}
```

and then:

```
public class A implements Settable {
    private int valore;
    public void set(int value) {
        valore = value;
    }
    public  void callClassB(){
        ClassB.Method(this);
    }
}
```

and in B:

```
public class B{      
    public void Method(Settable settable){
        settable.set(5);
    }
}
```